# Как получить разность дат, хранимых в DateField, выраженную в днях?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

У меня в Django есть модель `Event`, у которой есть поле с датой начала и датой конца. Мне нужно сделать вычисляемое поле `duration`, где будет высчитываться количество **дней** между датой начала и датой конца. Как работать с `DateField`, я вообще не понимаю.

```python
    start_date = models.DateField('Дата начала')
    end_date = models.DateField('Дата конца')
    
        # @property
        # def duration(self):
        # pass
```

Comment: Как именно Вы указываете дату начала и конца?

Comment: В базе данных есть два поля где помещаются даты в формате DD.MM.YYY

Answer (score 2):

Поле [`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) нормализуется в [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects), поэтому Вы можете вычитать одну дату из другой, получая [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

***Пример:***

```py
@property
def duration(self):
    return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days
```

Comment: Это не будет работать. Class 'DateField' does not define '__sub__'